# Função Deletar no PHP com mysql

Tags: php, mysql

Tenho a seguinte linha:

mysqli_query($conexao,"DELETE FROM itenspauta where CodItem=$recebecod3");

Porém ela exclui a linha toda, e eu só queria excluir apenas uma coluna desta tabela. Segue tabela:
[image: Tabela]

Eu queria excluir apenas a coluna de encaminhamentos, quando fosse solicitado. alguém tem dicas?

Comment: E o que ficaria, um "buraco" nela? O que você pode fazer, que faz mais sentido, é um UPDATE para valor vazio. `UPDATE tabela SET coluna = "" WHERE id=id_da_linha_desejada;`

Comment: *"Porém ela exclui a linha toda"*, sim, é exatamente isso que o comando `delete` faz, exclui uma linha. Não tem como excluir uma coluna do jeito que está pensando, você pode deixar ela com o valor *null* se ela permitir. Excluir uma coluna significa alterar a tabela e apagar a coluna inteira com todos os valores

Comment: Muito obrigado galera, era realmente o que precisava, consegui fazer aqui.

Comment: @VitorMatheus se resolveu, seria legal você postar abaixo, como resposta, e marcar como resolvido.

Comment: mysqli_query($conexao,"UPDATE itenspauta SET encaminhamento='' where CodItem=$recebecod3");

Comment: eu  resolvi desta forma acima, ^^